# Why maven does not support jpa 2.0?

Tags: jpa, maven-2

As far as I know JPA 2.0 has been approved as final in December 2009.

But the central repository gives the pom file declaration for 1.0.2 and 3.0-public_review.

So how can I use the current version of JPA 2.x using maven?

Comment: Usually you want a JPA provider/implementation, along with the JPA api. For example hibernate has its own repository which you can use, for downloading both.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api

Comment: Unlike all other standard Java APIs the javax.persistence API (group) seemingly were too lazy to release an "official" JPA 2.0 API and JPA 2.1 API jar, so you have to rely on the (unverified) javax.persistence provided by JPA implementations. See https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-19 and https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA itself is just the API definition, you'll need a provider who has implemented the API. I tend to use hibernate but there are others such as EclipseLink or OpenJPA. If you stick to just the core JPA functionality then you'll be able to swap providers at a later date easily enough.

Your choice of provider may be influenced if you're using a particular EE application server. JPA is part of the EE spec now but each server uses a different provider. E.G. JBoss uses hibernate while glassfish uses EclipseLink I believe.

With that in mind this is how I declare my hibernate dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This will automatically pull in the JPA 2.0 API jar along with other dependencies such as validation.